# Drop duplicate if the value in another column is null - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, drop-duplicates

What I have:

df

```
Name |Vehicle
```

---

```
Dave |Car
Mark |Bike
Steve|Car
Dave |
Steve|
```

I want to drop duplicates from the Name column but only if the corresponding value in Vehicle column is null.
I know I can use

```
 df.dropduplicates(subset=['Name'])
```

with either `Keep =` either `'First' or 'Last'` but what I am looking for is a way to drop duplicates from `Name` column where the corresponding value of `Vehicle` column is `null`. So basically, keep the `Name` if the `Vehicle` column is **NOT** null and drop the rest. If a name does not have a duplicate,then keep that row even if the corresponding value in `Vehicle` is null.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you need chain 2 masks with bitwise `OR` (`|`) with [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
m1 = df['Vehicle'].notna()
m2 = ~df['Name'].duplicated()

df1 = df[m1 & m2]
print (df1)
    Name Vehicle
0   Dave     Car
1   Mark    Bike
2  Steve     Car
```

If want these operations separately - first remove all NaNs rows and then remove duplicates for avoid testing duplicates in `NaN`s rows (if necessary):

```
df2 = df.dropna(subset=['Vehicle']).drop_duplicates('Name')
print (df2)
    Name Vehicle
0   Dave     Car
1   Mark    Bike
2  Steve     Car
```

Comment: Brilliant. Great logic! Thank you

Comment: This originally said bitwise `OR` (`|`), which is correct. Bitwise AND is wrong—that will drop rows with *either* duplicates in Name *or* NaN in Vehicle.

Comment: @AttilatheFun - ya, it depends. If added new line with `John,NaN` then need `&` if need remove this row or use `|` if need keepthis row.

Answer (score 2):

this will filter out both `None` and empty values (IF there are any non-`None` or non-empty values that is), keeping just the first encountered value for `Vehicle`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Dave", "Mark", "Steve", "Dave", "Steve"], "Vehicle": ["Car", "Bike", "Car", None, ""]})

res = df.sort_values("Vehicle", ascending=False).groupby("Name")["Vehicle"].first().reset_index()
```

Output:

```py
    Name Vehicle
0   Dave     Car
1   Mark    Bike
2  Steve     Car
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, but I made small adjustment.The default behavior for `.duplicated()` is to only flag the second and following instances.

```
df.duplicated(keep='false')
```

will tag both instances of the duplicates.  That gives us control over which instance is removed later on, instead of counting on the order of the rows to be exactly so that the first occurrence has the filled value for Vehicle.

Then

```
m1 = df["Vehicle"].isna()
m2 = df["Name", "Vehicle"].duplicated(keep="false")
# not(m1 and m2) == not(m1) or not(m2)
df = df[~m1 | ~m2] #keep non-duplicates or filled Vehicle or both
```

should keep the correct rows.