# Drop duplicated rows based on multiple columns if other column(s) is NaNs in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a test dataset as follows:

```
   id city district  quantity  price
0   1   bj       hd      12.0   23.0
1   2   bj       cy      23.0   45.0
2   3   bj       hd       NaN    NaN
3   4   bj       cy       NaN    NaN
4   5   sh       hp      12.0    NaN
5   6   sh       hp       NaN    NaN
6   7   sh       pd       NaN    NaN
```

I would like to drop duplicated rows based on `city` and `district`, then drop rows if its `quantity` is `NaN`, but if `city` and `district` are not duplicated, then even if `quantity` is `NaN`, it's not necessary to drop rows.

Code based on link from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532750/drop-duplicate-if-the-value-in-another-column-is-null-pandas):

```
m1 = df['quantity'].notna()
m2 = ~df[['city', 'district']].duplicated()

df1 = df[m1 & m2]
print(df1)
```

Out:

```
   id city district  quantity  price
0   1   bj       hd      12.0   23.0
1   2   bj       cy      23.0   45.0
4   5   sh       hp      12.0    NaN
```

But I want to keep the last row since it's not duplicated with any rows. How could I do that?

```
   id city district  quantity  price
0   1   bj       hd      12.0   23.0
1   2   bj       cy      23.0   45.0
2   5   sh       hp      12.0    NaN
3   7   sh       pd       NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your logic, it seems like you want to drop columns where:

1. `quantity` is `NaN` => `m1 = df['quantity'].isna()` AND
2. `'city', 'district'` is `duplicated` => `m2 = df[['city', 'district']].duplicated(keep=False)`

And since you would like to take all columns except which meet the above conditions:

```
>>> m1 = df['quantity'].isna()
>>> m2 = df[['city', 'district']].duplicated(keep=False)
>>> df[~(m1 & m2)]

   id city district  quantity  price
0   1   bj       hd      12.0   23.0
1   2   bj       cy      23.0   45.0
4   5   sh       hp      12.0    NaN
6   7   sh       pd       NaN    NaN
```

And your original code would work with `keep=False` and `|` (or) operator.

```
>>> m1 = df['quantity'].notna()
>>> m2 = ~df[['city', 'district']].duplicated(keep=False)
>>> df[m1 | m2]
   id city district  quantity  price
0   1   bj       hd      12.0   23.0
1   2   bj       cy      23.0   45.0
4   5   sh       hp      12.0    NaN
6   7   sh       pd       NaN    NaN
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, if the df is:

```
>>> df
   id city district  quantity  price
0   1   bj       hd      12.0   23.0
1   2   bj       cy      23.0   45.0
2   3   bj       hd       NaN    NaN
3   4   bj       cy       NaN    NaN
4   8   sh       hp      14.0   15.0
5   8   sh       hp      14.0   16.0
6   7   sh       pd       NaN    NaN

# First drop duplicates with NaN items, with any of the above methods
>>> df[m1 | m2]
   id city district  quantity  price
0   1   bj       hd      12.0   23.0
1   2   bj       cy      23.0   45.0
4   8   sh       hp      14.0   15.0
5   8   sh       hp      14.0   16.0
6   7   sh       pd       NaN    NaN

# then drop duplicates with default condition:
>>> df[m1 | m2].drop_duplicates(['city', 'district'])
   id city district  quantity  price
0   1   bj       hd      12.0   23.0
1   2   bj       cy      23.0   45.0
4   8   sh       hp      14.0   15.0
6   7   sh       pd       NaN    NaN
```

You can change `keep` parameter of `drop_duplicates` to control default behavior, i.e. whether to keep the `first` duplicate or the `last`.

Comment: I'm trying to do is to find duplicated rows based on the `city` and `district` columns. If the `quantity` is `NaN`, the rows with `NaN` `quantity` will be deleted first (it is also possible to judge whether multiple columns are `NaN`s); if it is not `NaN`, drop duplicated rows according to the default conditions.

Comment: I see, then all you need to do is, add another `..drop_duplicates(['city', 'district'])` after any of the above solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
m1 = df['quantity'].notna()
m2 = ~df[['city', 'district']].duplicated()
m3 = ~df[['city', 'district']].duplicated(keep=False)

df1 = df[(m1 & m2) | (~m1 & m3)]
print(df1)
   id city district  quantity  price
0   1   bj       hd      12.0   23.0
1   2   bj       cy      23.0   45.0
4   5   sh       hp      12.0    NaN
6   7   sh       pd       NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks but how does that ensure the rows droped are the ones whose `quantity` are `NaN`s?

Comment: @ahbon - Added another condition for test all non duplicated values, with `keep=False` for get all non duplicated NaNs